# How to change the Header Text of Gridview after Databound?

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-3.5

I have a gridview I bound a DataTable with that Gridview Its dynamic so no hardcode Text in desin.

I tried to change it after Databound and in PreRender of gridview but no Success.

Actually there are Underscores('_') in text and I want to Replace it with space.

Below is code

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdSearchResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Width="99%" OnPreRender="grdSearchResult_PreRender"
            OnRowCreated="grdSearchResult_OnRowCreated" OnPageIndexChanging="grdSearchResult_PageIndexChanging">
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" BackColor="#215B8D" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="gridtext" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>



protected void grdSearchResult_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grdSearchResult.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        grdSearchResult.Columns[i].HeaderText = grdSearchResult.Columns[i].HeaderText.Replace("_", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can do this with `RowDataBound` event of `GridView`

```
protected void grdSearchResult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Replace("_", " ");
        }
     }
}
```

and it works fine.

Comment: That will work, it'll just be done every time a row is bound.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the text of the cell rather than the HeaderText property:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < grdSearchResult.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            grdSearchResult.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text = grdSearchResult.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text.Replace("_", "");
        }
```

You don't need to do this in PreRender, just after the data has been bound.

Comment: Got this to work using `grdSearchResult.HeaderRow.Cells.Count` instead of `grdSearchResult.Columns.Count`

Comment: This one served my purpose. Called right after gridview.DataBind() in page_load event.

Answer (score 2):

Set AutoGenerateColumns property of gridview to false and add BoundFields.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="empNo" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="fName" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="lName" />
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

But in OnRowDataBound event the original e.Row.Cell[i].Text is not available for altering.

Eg. in the code below the "headerRow" is always empty.

```
protected void grdSearchResult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            string headerRow = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = headerRow.Replace("_", " ");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running into this problem...  The `HeaderRow` property is null when I attempt to use it during the `Page_Load` event.  Searching here to see when, where, and how I ought to access the header.

Answer (score 0):

If your header is more complex than the other examples (eg. sort buttons) use:

```
protected void gvMain_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow oRow = e.Row;
        if (oRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            foreach (TableCell oCell in oRow.Cells)
            {
                foreach (var oCtl in oCell.Controls) {
                    if(oCtl.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label))
                    {
                        Label oLBL = (Label)oCtl;

                        oLBL.Text = oLBL.Text.Replace("_", "");
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```