# GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Text Here" Throws "Index was out of range." Exception

Tags: asp.net, gridview

The following code;

```
 ViewState["lines"] = _Lines;
  GridView1.Visible = true;// Sets visibility on Datalist1.
  GridView1.DataSource = _Lines;
  GridView1.DataBind(); // Binds to to Datasource
  GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Text Here";
```

Gets an "Index was out of range exception. But the Gridview has six Columns when being rendered dynamically.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `_Lines` look like?

Comment: in this instance it has six columns. Labeled itemNumber, description, unitPrice, quantity, netWeight and netPrice.

Comment: If your columns are auto-generated, they will not be a part of Columns collection. But you can get to them via `RowDataBound` event. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3758699/961695

Comment: Thanks Yuriy! I just added OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound" to the GridView Declaration, and then created the method that replaces the text! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yuriy Galanter for the answer!

I just added `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` to GridView1's Declaration and then created the following method.

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Replace("net", "Net ");
            }
        }
    }
```